# How do I uninstall VQMOD from OpenCart 3.0.2.0?

Tags: opencart-3, vqmod

I suspect VQmod is the source of some CPU usage issues I'm running into and desperately need to uninstall it. Yet I can find no documentation on how to do so.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a backup of `index.php` and `admin/index.php` and the `vqmod` folder to avoid unexpected problems.
2. Replace `index.php` and `admin/index.php` with the fresh copy of these files form the OpenCart installation pack.
3. Remove or rename `vqmod` folder.